# Working with index, local variable and class

Tags: c#, indexing

In the code below, I am trying to use indexing with item.Number
It looks like I cannot compare `if (item.Number[index] == decimalNumbers[j])` like this and getting the error "c# cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'int'"

If anyone can guide me to the right direction. 
Also, code is not a complete code. I just want to understand the reasoning.

```
public class NumberWithDifference
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public static int[] decimalNumbers = new int[10]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    foreach (var item in jagged.Items)
    {
        i = true;
        int index = 0;
        var a = item.Number;

        for (int j = 0; j < decimalNumbers.Length; j++)
        {
            if (item.Number[index] == decimalNumbers[j])
            {
                Console.Write(decimalNumbers[j]);
                i = false;

                if (index < item.Number.Length - 1)
                        index++;
            }

            else
            {
                Console.Write(0);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: you already using foreach, so it will be individual item

Comment: it means item.Number is not array but int. SO, use item.number = . Also looks like you dont need index as you are using foreach

Comment: @KrishnaDhugana - foreach is being used with decimalnumbers....I am comparing different item.number values with different decimalnumber values

Comment: Can you post the structure of  the variable type 'jagged' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message states, item.Number is an int. Indexing can be applied to an array or list of ints, but not to a single int value.

Thus, this code below,

```
if (item.Number[index] == decimalNumbers[j])
```

should really be

```
if (item.Number == decimalNumbers[j])
```

Assuming jagged is an array of NumberWithDifference, you could also do the following instead:

```
for (int j = 0; j < decimalNumbers.Length; j++)
{
    if (jagged[index].Number == decimalNumbers[j])
    {
        etc...
```

Comment: @abhi, could you please share the error message you got when you tried the above?

Comment: here is the error message "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'JaggedData'"

Comment: Ah okay, in that case, it looks like JaggedData is a custom data type that doesn't support indexing. You would either need to define an indexer for JaggedData (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/index), or just use `if (item.Number == decimalNumbers[j])`